# Json transformation using jq

Tags: linux, json, jq

I want to transform json to new line delimited json. 
I was attempting to do it multiple times using jq in bash, but I have not been able to get even close to the final output.

INPUT:

```
{
    "windows124": {
        "updated": "2015-01-14",
        "attribution": [],
        "description": "",
        "notes": [],
        "alt_names": [],
        "sources": [],
        "urls": ["google.com", "google.co.uk"],
        "common_name": "test",
        "uuid": "7259334c-3218-4259-aaab-896d87507f4f"
    },
    "linux124": {
        "updated": "",
        "attribution": ["Naifdddkoscn"],
        "description": "",
        "notes": [],
        "alt_names": [],
        "sources": [],
        "urls": ["https://example.com/1.pdf", "https://example.com/1.pdf", "https://example.com/1.pdf"],
        "common_name": "121212",
        "uuid": "009db412-762d-4256-8df9-eb213be01ffd"
    },
    "wikipedia123": {
        "updated": "2018-07-31",
        "attribution": [],
        "description": "",
        "notes": [],
        "alt_names": [],
        "sources": [],
        "urls": ["https://example.com/1.pdf"],
        "common_name": "test343",
        "uuid": "4d8da0af-cfd7-4990-b211-af0e990vfda0"
    }
}
```

WANTED OUTPUT:

```
{"uuid": "7259334c-3218-4259-aaab-896d87507f4f","family": "windows124","updated": "2015-01-14","attribution": [],"description": "","notes": [],"alt_names": [],"sources": [],"urls": ["google.com", "google.co.uk"],"common_name": "test"}
{"uuid": "009db412-762d-4256-8df9-eb213be01ffd","family": "linux124", "updated": "","attribution": ["Naifdddkoscn"],"description": "","notes": [],"alt_names": [],"sources": [],"urls": ["https://example.com/1.pdf", "https://example.com/1.pdf", "https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name": "121212"}
{"uuid": "4d8da0af-cfd7-4990-b211-af0e990vfda0","family": "wikipedia123", "updated": "2018-07-31","attribution": [],"description": "","notes": [],"alt_names": [],"sources": [],"urls": ["https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name": "test343"}
```

What I have so far is: 
cat deserialize.json | jq  -c '.|to_entries[]'

```
{"key":"windows124","value":{"updated":"2015-01-14","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["google.com","google.co.uk"],"common_name":"test","uuid":"7259334c-3218-4259-aaab-896d87507f4f"}}
{"key":"linux124","value":{"updated":"","attribution":["Naifdddkoscn"],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://example.com/1.pdf","https://example.com/1.pdf","https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name":"121212","uuid":"009db412-762d-4256-8df9-eb213be01ffd"}}
{"key":"wikipedia123","value":{"updated":"2018-07-31","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name":"test343","uuid":"4d8da0af-cfd7-4990-b211-af0e990vfda0"}}
```

Comment: Got closer with : jq '.|to_entries[]'

Comment: You can add the `-c` (`--compact-output`) command line option if you don't want the output pretty-printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this jq filter:

```
<file jq 'to_entries|map(.value + {family:(.key)})[]'
```

As you found out, the `to_entries` function allows to get the key name in order add the property `family`.

So the filter only creates this `family` object and adds it to the content of the `value` given by `to_entries` function.

The `map` function does the add operation to all elements of the `value` array.

The final `[]` gets rid of the outer array.

Note the output is not order in the way you posted, but the content is same. If you want the keys to be sorted, use the option `-S`.

Comment: Thanks $oliv. Nicely done. Have you solved similar issue before, or how did you figure that out? If you can, please let me know how I could replicate your steps differently than doing brute force on all options.

Comment: @creed The way to solve this type of problem is indeed to try out. Read the man pages and go to the jq website to get to know the functions and how to use it. In other words, learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
jq -c 'with_entries(.value.family = .key)[]' file.json
```

or,

```bsh
jq -c 'with_entries(.value += { family: .key })[]' file.json
```

This inserts a `family` key into each sub-element of the original top-level object, with the value of the key of that element (e.g. `windows124` for the first one).  It then returns the sub-element as a set, which is what you appear to want.

Output for the document given in the question:

```json
{"updated":"2015-01-14","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["google.com","google.co.uk"],"common_name":"test","uuid":"7259334c-3218-4259-aaab-896d87507f4f","family":"windows124"}
{"updated":"","attribution":["Naifdddkoscn"],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://example.com/1.pdf","https://example.com/1.pdf","https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name":"121212","uuid":"009db412-762d-4256-8df9-eb213be01ffd","family":"linux124"}
{"updated":"2018-07-31","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://example.com/1.pdf"],"common_name":"test343","uuid":"4d8da0af-cfd7-4990-b211-af0e990vfda0","family":"wikipedia123"}
```